# Why my heap mem is always increasing? How to debug?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, memory, memory-management

I have two views in my ipad app: one displays a list of records and the other displays the detailed record (including a photo and some text).

When user swipes left/right in the detail view, the root view controller will destroy the detail view controller and create a new one for the next/previous photo.

When I use the allocation profiling, my heap mem is always increasing as I browse through the photos.

I release all the UI controls in my detail view's dealloc method, though I am not sure if it's necessary to release the UIImageView and UILabels from XIB file.

And I used the leak profiling and didn't find any leak while I browse along.

Even after I have looped back all the photos, it will still increase when I destroy & create detailed view controller.

If it's not a leak, what's happening?

Thanks

Leo

Comment: put a breakpoint in second view controller dealloc and see whether it gets called

Comment: we can guess so little of your problem since we dont know what you are doing in the code. Or post some code..

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is very generic, and you haven't provided any code I can only recommend you to take a look at WWDC's Session 311 - Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments video, which gives a good primer on finding (and fixing) various memory related problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try with running with Instruments.

In your xcode run-> Run with Performance Tool-> Leaks.

This will show the Memory Leaks in the application.